# Error trying to use MailKit to send Email "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time"

Tags: c#, .net-core, mailkit

Getting an error when I try to send emails using MailKit. Using port 587 and host is a Barracuda server. Email still manages to send but breaks at client.Send(mail) and gives this error below.

Does anyone know what I'm missing or doing wrong? I can provide more code if needed.

Send mail code:

```
                       client.Connect(_SMTPOptions.Host, _SMTPOptions.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                       client.Timeout = 1000;
                       client.Send(mail);
                       client.Disconnect(true);
```

Add attachement code (if this matters):

```
                       bytes = bytes + document.Bytes.Length;
                       Stream stream = new MemoryStream(document.Bytes);
                       streamlist.Add(stream);
                       var attachment = new MimePart("application","pdf")
                       {
                           Content = new MimeContent(stream, ContentEncoding.Default),
                           ContentDisposition = new MimeKit.ContentDisposition(MimeKit.ContentDisposition.Attachment),
                           ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                           FileName = Path.GetFileName(order.OrderNumber + "_" + document.DocumentType + "_" + document.IntDocID + ".pdf")
                       };

                       builder.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Error Message:

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**

StackTrace:

**StackTrace:   at MailKit.Net.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.Read(Span 1 buffer)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory 1 buffer)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadAheadAsync(Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponseAsync(Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpStream.ReadResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.DataAsync(FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, Int64 size, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.SendAsync(FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress sender, IList`1 recipients, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.Send(FormatOptions options, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
at MailKit.MailTransport.Send(MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be this line:

```
client.Timeout = 1000;
```

You are telling MailKit to throw an exception after 1000 milliseconds (aka 1 second) if it cannot read from (or write to) a socket within that time period.

The default timeout that MailKit uses is 2 minutes (`2 * 60 * 1000`).

Comment: I noticed this too and removed it. Still got the same errors unfortunately.

Comment: Try getting a [protocol log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) and taking a look at the last few lines of the `DATA` command. Does the last line look like `C: .` ?